# SEO Microdata (data-vocabulary.org, schema.org ) and HTML5

Tags: html, seo, schema.org

I have just read a lot of different information about Data-Vocabulary.org and Schema.org about how it's good for SEO. But I'm really not sure that anyone uses it in a real site. Am I right?

If not can someone provide some links to real site with this stuff?

And second question does it make sense to use it in HTML5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search on Google for any restaurant, or destination covered by TripAdvisor or Yelp (in other words, any restaurant or destination) and you'll see the magic of microformats at work -- see the rating stars and other meta-information?

And yes: use them.  And yes, follow schema.org guidelines.  And no, it doesn't matter at all which version of HTML you use them in, so write in HTML 5 and do other good things.

Whether they help for SEO is a somewhat different question.  Microformats are unlikely to have a significant influence on your site's rankings as long as you use them as suggested.

However, take a look at the pages that have them and are able to influence what a search engine displays when it lists your site.  While some have argued that "there's no need to click through if all the information is summarized" this has not proven to be true in practice.  (See this article http://searchengineland.com/how-to-use-rich-snippets-structured-markup-for-high-powered-seo-99081).  In short, having microformats that distinguish your site from others is good for everyone.